Joy Tabs lose data component inside tabPanel
If I create a tabs with tab Panel where inside I have a child component with  tag . After editing this input and I change the tab. When I come back to the tab where I editing data before. The data is loose. I try with the tab of Antd and it's handling well. But I like Joy. Can you help me?
I Expect when I change the element child inside the tabPanel the element edited not lose when change the new tab.
